# mplsoccer plotting reversed pass network

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

[image]

Hi all,
As you can see this is the passnetwork of one of liverpool game. If I compare this passnetwork with the lineup then T Alexander Arnold and Mohammed Salah should be on the right side and not on the left side. The quastion is what did I do wrong.
Is it by merging the passer and recipient?
Is it by grouping?
Is it by plotting the passes?

See the code below

Thanks in advance

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from mplsoccer.pitch import Pitch
from mplsoccer.pitch import VerticalPitch
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba
from mplsoccer import Pitch, FontManager
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

#set options to display the mxa_rows and max columns
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
#read in csv
dataframe = pd.read_csv('LIVERPOOLvsWOLVES.csv')

#Select only the relevant columns
dataframe = dataframe [["event/eventId","event/timeMin","event/timeSec","event/playerName",
                               "event/playerId","event/outcome","event/x","event/y","event/contestantId",
                               "event/qualifier/0/qualifierId","event/qualifier/0/value",
                               "event/qualifier/1/qualifierId","event/qualifier/1/value",
                               "event/qualifier/2/qualifierId","event/qualifier/2/value",
                               "event/qualifier/3/qualifierId","event/qualifier/3/value",
                               "event/qualifier/4/qualifierId","event/qualifier/4/value",
                               "event/qualifier/5/qualifierId","event/qualifier/5/value",
                               "event/qualifier/6/qualifierId","event/qualifier/6/value",
                               "event/qualifier/7/qualifierId","event/qualifier/7/value",
                               "event/qualifier/8/qualifierId","event/qualifier/8/value",
                               ]]
                               
#Sort now only the wanted team in this case liverpool
dataframe = dataframe[dataframe['event/contestantId']== 'c8h9bw1l82s06h77xxrelzhur']
#Sort now only the successful passes outcome 1
dataframe = dataframe[dataframe['event/outcome']==1]

#rename 22 columns 
dataframe.rename({'event/qualifier/0/qualifierId':'eventqualifier0qualifierId'},axis='columns',inplace=True) + 21 columns


#Add two extra columns
dataframe["endX"]=""
dataframe["endY"]=""

#fill the endX and the endY 
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dataframe)

#loop through all rows and get the x_end and y_end
def get_final_values(row):
    for i in range(0,8):
        if row[f'eventqualifier{i}qualifierId'] == 140:
            row['endX'] = row[f'eventqualifier{i}value']
        elif row[f'eventqualifier{i}qualifierId'] == 141:
            row['endY'] = row[f'eventqualifier{i}value']
    return row

dataframe = dataframe.apply(get_final_values,axis=1)

#Add two extra columns 
dataframe['passer'] = dataframe['event/playerName']
dataframe['recipient'] = dataframe['event/playerName'].shift(-1)

#1-remove now the dublicated rows  for all the players df.drop(df[(df.score < 50) & (df.score > 20)].index) for player Stefan Bajčetić
dataframe = dataframe.drop(
    dataframe[(dataframe.passer =='Stefan Bajčetić')&(dataframe.recipient =='Stefan Bajčetić')].index)
    
#Remove the empty rows of endX and endY
dataframe = dataframe.drop(
    dataframe[(dataframe.endX =='')&
                                (dataframe.endY =='')].index)
                                
#filter the dataframe untill the first subtitutionOff
dataframe = dataframe[
    dataframe['event/timeMin']<75]
    
#Filter now again only the needed columns
dataframe = dataframe [["event/eventId","event/timeMin","event/timeSec","event/playerName",
                        "event/playerId","event/outcome","x","y","event/contestantId",
                        "endX","endY","passer","recipient"
                               ]]
                               
#Rename some columns
dataframe.rename({'event/playerName':'playerName'},axis='columns',inplace=True)
dataframe.rename({'event/playerId':'playerId'},axis='columns',inplace=True)

#Create the average location
average_locations = dataframe.groupby('passer').agg({'x':['mean'],'y':['mean','count']})
average_locations.columns = ['x','y','count']

#find the number of passes between each player
#pass_between = sorted_df_SuccessfullPasses[sorted_df_SuccessfullPasses['event/timeMin']<75]

pass_between = dataframe.groupby(['passer','recipient'], as_index=False).playerId.count().reset_index()
pass_between.rename({'playerId':'pass_count'},axis='columns',inplace=True)

#Merge now the average location and pass_between
pass_between = pass_between.merge(average_locations, left_on='passer', right_index=True)
pass_between = pass_between.merge(average_locations, left_on='recipient', right_index=True,suffixes=['','_end'])

MAX_LINE_WIDTH = 18
MAX_MARKER_SIZE = 3000
pass_between['width'] = (pass_between.pass_count / pass_between.pass_count.max() * MAX_LINE_WIDTH)
average_locations['marker_size'] = (average_locations['count']
                                         / average_locations['count'].max() * MAX_MARKER_SIZE)
                                         
MIN_TRANSPARENCY = 0.3
color = np.array(to_rgba('white'))
color = np.tile(color, (len(pass_between), 1))
c_transparency = pass_between.pass_count / pass_between.pass_count.max()
c_transparency = (c_transparency * (1 - MIN_TRANSPARENCY)) + MIN_TRANSPARENCY
color[:, 3] = c_transparency

#Now plotting
pitch = Pitch(pitch_type='statsbomb', pitch_color='black', line_color='#c7d5cc')

fig, ax = pitch.draw(figsize=(16, 11), constrained_layout=True, tight_layout=False)

fig.set_facecolor("#22312b")

arrows = pitch.arrows(1.2*pass_between.x,    .8*pass_between.y,
                      1.2*pass_between.x_end,.8*pass_between.y_end, ax=ax,
                     width = 3, headwidth= 3, color='white', zorder =1, alpha = .5)

arrows = pitch.lines(1.2*pass_between.x,    .8*pass_between.y,
                     1.2*pass_between.x_end,.8*pass_between.y_end,lw=pass_between.width,
                         color=color, zorder=1, ax=ax)
    
nodes = pitch.scatter(1.2*average_locations.x,.8*average_locations.y,
                     s = average_locations.marker_size, color = 'red', edgecolors = 'black', linewidth = 2.5, alpha = 1, zorder = 1, ax=ax)
                      
for index, row in average_locations.iterrows():
    pitch.annotate(row.name, xy=(1.2*row.x, .8*row.y), c='white', va='center',
                   ha='center', size=16, weight='bold', ax=ax)
```

Comment: Without sharing the code, it is not possible for people to write an answer. The expectation is that all necessary code is provided in the question itself, in the form of a minimal, verifiable, self contained example.

Comment: Hi nanofarad, I have added the code.

Comment: And, can you add the actual/expected lineup? Without having seen this game or knowing the team's lineup, is it possible that your Y coordinates are simply backwards, causing mirroring in that axis?

Comment: https://www.sofascore.com/liverpool-wolverhampton/dsU

Comment: Again, the question presupposes specific domain knowledge, and we aren't likely to review the game to see specific pass details, but it does seem like generally there's simply a flip in the Y axis here.

Comment: Hi nanofarad, maybe you are right. I will look into the csv file and check again. Plotting the pass map of a specific player is showing me perfectly the right position of the player on the pitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I was using statsbomb pitch. I have changed it to opta.